# To delete all documents from a firestore collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to use this method:

```
deleteMessages(){
    this.firestore.collection("MESSAGES")
  .get()
  .then(res => {res.forEach(element => {element.ref.delete();});

      });
     }
```

But I receive the following error message :

> Property 'then' does not exist on type
> 'Observable<QuerySnapshot>'.

Then I opted for the following:

```
deleteTheMessages() {
      const messagesCollection= this.firestore.collection<Message>('MESSAGES').get();
  
      messagesCollection.toPromise().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.delete());
      });
    }
```

[toPromise was struck :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMQQG.png)

Then I had this message when tried to ng build

> error: src/app/messages.service.ts:37:9 - error TS2532: Object is
> possibly 'undefined'.
>
> 37         snapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.delete());

with ~~~~~~~~ under the word snapshot.

Couldn't solve both, so if you have any suggestion I will thankful.

Comment: Since yuo're using AngularFire, you might need to use `first()` ( or `take(1)`) instead of `get()`.

Comment: Why don't you add a check in your callback to make sure snapshot has a value other than undefined?

Comment: @DougStevenson It worked thanks allot! with "if(snapshot)"


messagesCollection.toPromise().then((snapshot) => {if(snapshot)
                  snapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.delete());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a check-in as @Doug Stevenson suggested:

```
if(snapshot)
```